# Emulating a Terminal with a GridPane

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to create an embedded terminal window in my project. The terminal history is grid pane filled will a single column of labels (The terminal listens to a TextField and when the user presses enter, the line is added to the history).

[image: Screenshot of the terminal.]

```java
public class Terminal extends BorderPane {

    final private GridPane historyPane;
    final private TextField inputField;

    public Terminal() {
        super.setId( "TerminalParent" );
        historyPane = createHistoryPane();
        inputField = createInputField();

        super.setBottom( inputField );
        super.setCenter( historyPane );
    }

    private GridPane createHistoryPane() {
        final GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setId( "TerminalHistoryPane" );
        return pane;
    }

    private void addHistory( String str ) {
        final Label label = new Label( str );
        label.getStyleClass().add( "TerminalHistoryLabel" );
        historyPane.addRow( historyPane.getRowCount(), label );
    }

    private TextField createInputField() {
        final TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setId( "TerminalTextField" );
        field.setOnKeyPressed( ( event ) -> {
            if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER ) {
                addHistory( field.getText() );
                field.clear();
            }
        } );
        return field;
    }
}
```

*CSS*

```css
* {
    -terminal-text-color: #FB0;
    -terminal-foreground-color: #0FF;
    -terminal-background-color: black;
}

#TerminalParent {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-pref-width: 400;
}

#TerminalTextField {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-family: "FreeMono";
    -fx-font-size: 16;
    -fx-background-color: -terminal-background-color;
    -fx-border-color: -terminal-foreground-color;
    -fx-text-fill: -terminal-text-color;
}

#TerminalHistoryPane {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-font-family: "FreeMono";
    -fx-font-size: 16;
    -fx-text-fill: -terminal-text-color;
    -fx-background-color: -terminal-background-color;
    -fx-border-color: -terminal-foreground-color;
}

.TerminalHistoryLabel {
    -fx-text-fill: -terminal-text-color;
    -fx-font-family: "FreeMono";
}
```

Currently, the lines start at the top and are written downwards. When they reach the bottom, the grid pane starts to grow with them. Instead, I would like to flip it so that the first row starts at the bottom and new rows push the old ones up (this can be achieved by manually shifting them up by one). When they reach the top of the pane, I'd like for the pane to be scrollable.

Comment: You should probably be using ListView instead of GridPane.

Comment: .. or a read-only TextArea